# maven resources plugin - How to filter from external file?

Tags: maven, properties-file

I need to configure some `log4j2.xml` file based on some properties and those properties vary according to the environment. For example I set `log.org.hibernate=info` for development and `log.org.hibernate=error` for production etc.

I'm using maven resources plugin as shown below and it's working fine.

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
<filters>
    <filter>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/env/prod.properties</filter>
</filters>
```

Now I need to filter external properties file and set those properties to the same `log4j2.xml` file. But AFAIK resources plugin doesn't allow external file filtering.

How can I read the properties from external properties file (outside of my project directory) and set them to an inner resource (such as `log4j2.xml` file)?

Comment: What do you mean `external properties file`, a file outside of your project directory?

Comment: Yes. As I told in the question I can already use `${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/env/prod.properties` file, which is obviously a file inside of my project directory. And by `external properties file` I mean, a file outside of my project directory.